# git merge, keep both

Tags: git, git-merge

For merging I use this to "keep mine"

```
git merge -X ours foo
```

and this for "keep theirs"

```
git merge -X theirs foo
```

However on my latest merge it looks best to keep both sides. Does Git have a "strategy" for this, to avoid manually editing the file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no 'merge strategy' for resolving these conflicts.

However, if you truly want a conflict like:

```
<<<< ours
Foo
=========
Bar 
>>>> theirs
```

to resolve to

```
Foo
Bar
```

then you can configure the 'merge driver'.  From the [gitattributes](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) man page:

> union
>
> Run 3-way file level merge for text files, but take lines from
>   both versions, instead of leaving conflict markers. This tends to
>   leave the added lines in the resulting file in random order and the
>   user should verify the result. Do not use this if you do not
>   understand the implications.

Add a line to .gitattributes to use this:

```
*.whatever merge=union
```

Comment: Union does not map to "keep both". Union is "keep both" minus intersection. This will fail horribly when trying to "keep both" on XML like resource files.

Comment: In case when 2 diff hunks conflict, they seem to be kept both, fully.

Comment: but there's no way to add this as an option (if we don't consider editing `.gitattributes` to be an 'option') that can be called specifcally for conflicts that you want to merge this way? these are so common it would be so nice to have a way to one-line-cli them (multiple imports / functions / properties added to the same file and order doesn't matter)

Comment: What is the ".*whatever" supposed to connote here? It's clear at all

Comment: Also, at what point do I add this line to .gitattributes, and then what do I after (or before) to get the "union" merge to occur?

Comment: @BrianPeterson `whatever` is the file extension - see [.gitignore pattern format](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) which is the same.

Comment: @dwight-holman I can't get your solution to work. Would you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369712/how-to-use-git-merge-union? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71369712/205696)

Comment: Great answer, been looking through git docs for this exactly

Answer (score 11):

What about this one?

`grep -v -e'^<<<<<<<' -e '^>>>>>>>' -e'=======' filename.txt > filename.tmp`

`mv filename.tmp filename.txt`

Comment: This will omit lines that were the same in theirs and ours. I guess it's called the intersection. At the point of merge where you have the above strings ("<<<" etc) git has already removed "duplicate" lines that I actually want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a large chunk of code needs conflict resolution. When I want to keep *both*, I do this:

1. Copy the whole code chunk. So, two instances are there.
2. Remove the `HEAD` or *ours* sections on the 1st instance.
3. Remove the to-be-merged or *their* sections on the 2nd instance.

Comment: The question was how to "avoid manually editing the file". That means don't do exactly what this answer does.

Comment: @matt Well, sorry, I didn't notice that.