# git: can I accept both changes in a merge conflict without editing files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I usually have merge conflicts on Rails locale files, for example:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  label_company_offices: "Branches"
=======
  field_amounts_withheld: "Withheld amount"
>>>>>>> master
```

here I have to edit every locale file, can I avoid this?

there's any way to tell git "resolve conflict accepting both changes"?

Comment: There is, sort of. This is called a *union merge*. Don't do it! Or (for experts only): don't do it yet.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38502458/1256452 for details.

Comment: thanks for the link, I searched but wasn't able to find it :(
I don't like the idea to have to check if merge was made correctly every time, if git doesn't support this, I think a script with `sed` can do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the job for me:

```
ruby -pi -e "gsub(/^[=<>*]{7}.*\n/,'')" config/locales/*.yml
```

used in a bash alias:

```
alias automerge="ruby -pi -e \"gsub(/^[=<>*]{7}.*\\n/,'')\""
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be manually resolving all merge conflicts before re-staging them ("git add") and completing the merge commit.

The only way to "accept both" would be to just re-stage (marking as resolved) the conflicted files without resolving them ( >>> and <<< would be there still), but your result couldnt be compiled or executed. And this is **terrible practice**, even if you make commits later to resolve. The point of the merge commit is to see the resolution of the merge in the commit.

There are ways to avoid generating the conflicts - using merge strategies. For example, you can pass a strategy parameter to the "git merge" command to always take your change in a conflict using the "ours" strategy. Look at the "git merge" help page to see the different strategies and maybe one will apply to your situation.

Comment: what I want is to automatically remove the git marks so then I can do `git add` and accept both changes