# When resolving conflicts during a rebase, is there a native command for accepting both changes?

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

A merge conflict occurred during a rebase, and Git is now asking me to resolve the patch. In cases where both changes are acceptable, how do I tell Git to accept both changes without having to modify the file myself?

E.g. when both changes are acceptable:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
const foo = require('./foo');
=======
const bar = require('./bar');
>>>>>>> some commit message
```

[git: can I accept both changes in a merge conflict without editing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40673017/2687324) suggests a way to do this for a very specific case without using Git, but I'm looking to do this with native Git commands. [A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673017/git-can-i-accept-both-changes-in-a-merge-conflict-without-editing-files#comment68576320_40673017) mentions doing a union merge, but I couldn't find docs around how to do this in this scenario.

Comment: Even if Git provides such a command you still need to visually inspect each conflict and decide how to combine the changes. Maybe some of them need *yours* before *theirs* while others need *their* before *yours*. Both ways look valid for the posted conflict but most of the times it's not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

To do a union merge, you must first extract *all three* inputs:

```
git show :1:$path > base
git show :2:$path > ours
git show :3:$path > theirs
```

(these file names are purely for illustration—in practice you would need to generate a unique temporary file name for most of these file), then run `git merge-file`:

```
git merge-file --union ours base theirs
```

The merged result is now in the file named `ours`; `base` and `theirs` may be discarded.

(Git probably should include a script that does the three extractions, runs `git merge-file` with any of the ours, theirs, or union options, and puts the result into the work-tree for inspection.  It doesn't, but I think it should.)

You must be very careful with union-merge, as it always *thinks* it succeeded, even if it made a mess of the result.

Comment: I would add that this `:N:path/to/a/file` notation is explained in the [`gitrevisions(7)` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) — @neverendingqs, run `git help revisions` to read it.