# Is there a git merge strategy or strategy option for "take both"?

Tags: git

I guess "octopus" strategy sounds a bit like this, though I don't understand the complexities.

What I'd really like to be able to do is take file-level merge conflicts and just apply all changes. 
Perhaps as a consequence, I would be OK with the order of theirs / ours not being deterministic.

This would be nifty, though probably not a huge feature for a lot of people. For example, something like:

`git merge my-branch -X both` or `git merge -s naive`?

Curious if anyone has used something like this.

Comment: you can always create your own merging strategy and apply it using the .gitattributes mechanism.

Comment: If I do get you right, you basically want the file in the state git leaves them on the file system when there are merge conflicts. minus the `<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>` lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git merge, keep both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263902/git-merge-keep-both)

Comment: It *asks* my question, but I don't feel it adequately answers it, because it's not clear how to or if it's really possible to get it working using the suggested approach. Should I say it answers my question, in that case?

Comment: What I understand is, you want to include all changes even if they are conflicting from ours and theirs side, and the resultant file will possibly contain duplicates ? and you don't want to resolve this conflict manually ? Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The usual term for this is *union merge*; see the link in [grg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421243/is-there-a-git-merge-strategy-or-strategy-option-for-take-both#comment106889869_60421243).  There is no `-s` strategy, and no `-X` eXtended-option to any of the existing strategies, to make the low level file merge use union merge.  You can, however, create a `.gitattributes` file and specify `merge=union` there, and the `git merge-file` command has a `--union` option, as well as the `--ours` and `--theirs` options.

(Presumably no one put `-X union` in as an extended argument to the existing recursive/resolve strategy because it is so relatively uncommon to want it.)

#### Discussion of merge strategies

The *octopus* strategy is very special: it implements a relatively simple merge that allows you to merge more than one other commit into the current (`HEAD`) commit.  It requires that this merge have *no* conflicts *anywhere* as it has no place to record all the temporary inputs.  The *resolve* and *recursive* strategies handle merge conflicts by copying the three input files—merge base, `--ours`, and `--theirs`—into the index, in the three index slots, and then using the existing `git merge-file` code<sup>1</sup> to merge those three files, writing conflict markers into the final output version.

Note that the `-s resolve` strategy, implemented by the `git merge-resolve` command, is the same as `git merge-recursive` (and implemented by the same underlying code) with one exception: if `git merge-recursive` finds two or more merge base commits, `git merge -s resolve` simply picks one of them at random, while `git merge-recursive` first *merges the merge bases* to make a new commit, then uses the new commit as the merge base.

The `-s subtree` strategy is the recursive strategy; it just does some file renaming along the way.

The remaining strategy (`-s ours`) does not even compute a merge base since it is not actually doing any merging.

In effect, then, there are really only two *merge* strategies: recursive, and octopus.  The remaining strategies are just modifications of recursive, or not *merge* operations at all (`-s ours`).

You *can* write your own merge strategy.  Simply write any command, in any source language, and name the executable binary `git-merge-foo` or `git-merge-xyzzy` or whatever.  Running `git merge -s foo` or `git merge -s xyzzy` will now invoke *your* strategy, with undocumented arguments that you must puzzle out.  These arguments should drive your selection of a merge base and your merging process.  *Everything* is left to your own code, including how to define and implement the merge, and how to `git add` the resulting files to the index, and how to run `git commit` (if you're going to run it at all).  To make a future commit record an actual merge, your command should leave the correct bread-crumb-trail files in the Git directory (`git rev-parse --git-dir`) based on the current work-tree (since Git 2.5).

---

<sup>1</sup>It doesn't literally run `git merge-file`: instead, the base code for doing merges is in various source files, and both `git merge-file` and `git merge-recursive` invoke that same base code.  That code takes three inputs, and writes one output.  For `git merge-recursive`, the three inputs are stored in the index; for `git merge-file`, the three are stored in three file-system files.  The output in all cases is the work-tree copy of the file.  If the merge succeeds without conflicts, `git merge-recursive` moves that file to staging slot zero and proceeds without conflicts, but `git merge-file` simply exits with a zero status.  If that merge hits conflicts, or fails for other reasons, `git merge-recursive` leaves the mess behind in the index and your work-tree and moves on to the next file as usual, while `git merge-file` simply exits with a nonzero status.